# ASP.Net - Adding a new object that contains other objects but the contained objects become null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to add a Course object to my database and in my form I have 3 other objects that can be contained in the Course object. In my form, the other 3 objects show but when it returns to the controller, the 3 object values are null.

If more information is needed please let me know.

Why are the Teacher, Student, GradedWork values being returned as null?

My controller create methods

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var addForm = new CourseAddForm();

        addForm.Teachers = m.GetAllTeachersAsList();
        addForm.Students = m.GetAllStudentsAsList();
        addForm.GradedWorks = m.GetAllGradedWorkAsList();

        return View(addForm);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Course/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CourseAdd newItem)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var addedItem = m.AddCourse(newItem);

            if (addedItem == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = addedItem.Id });
            }


        }

        else
        {
            var addForm = Mapper.Map<CourseAddForm>(newItem);

            addForm.Teachers = m.GetAllTeachersAsList();
            addForm.Students = m.GetAllStudentsAsList();
            addForm.GradedWorks = m.GetAllGradedWorkAsList();

            return View(addForm);
        }
    }
```

My view models

```
public class CourseAddForm : CourseAdd
{

    [Display(Name = "Teacher")]
    public ICollection<TeacherList> Teachers { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Student")]
    public ICollection<StudentList> Students { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Graded Works")]
    public ICollection<GradedWorkList> GradedWorks { get; set; }

    public CourseAddForm()
    {
        this.Teachers = new List<TeacherList>();
        this.Students = new List<StudentList>();
        this.GradedWorks = new List<GradedWorkList>();

    }



}

public class CourseAdd
{

    //[Key]
    [Display(Name = "Course Code")]
    public int CourseCode { get; set; }

    // [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //  [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Semester")]
    public string Semester { get; set; }

    // [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Section Id")]
    public string SectionId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Teacher")]
    public ICollection<TeacherList> Teachers { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Student")]
    public ICollection<StudentList> Students { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Graded Works")]
    public ICollection<GradedWorkList> GradedWorks { get; set; }

}


public class CourseBase : CourseAdd
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

}


public class CourseBaseAddOn
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //[Key]
    [Display(Name = "Course Code")]
    public int CourseCode { get; set; }

    // [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //  [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Semester")]
    public string Semester { get; set; }

    // [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Section Id")]
    public string SectionId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Teacher")]
    public ICollection<TeacherList> Teachers { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Student")]
    public ICollection<StudentList> Students { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Graded Works")]
    public ICollection<GradedWorkList> GradedWorks { get; set; }

}
```

My manager method

```
public CourseBaseAddOn AddCourse(CourseAdd newItem)
    {

        Course course = Mapper.Map<Course>(newItem);

        ds.Courses.Add(course);
        ds.SaveChanges();

        return Mapper.Map<CourseBaseAddOn>(course);

    }
```

My form

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7abx.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

when you fill your collections and send to the view, view shows data and all of data,when send to the client, will destroyed. Therefore, you should create an element that kept your data to post to the server when you submit your form.

Comment: how would i go about doing that? The keeping an element that kept my data to post. assign an int that keeps the id of the object that was selected?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot the name="" attribute in my view form, with that I was able to locate the ID and then assign the object where id==Id manually